# CompareValidator without RequiredFieldValidator?

Tags: c#, asp.net, comparevalidator

So I've been looking all over and can't seem to find a similar problem.

Basically, it seems like using `CompareValidator` doesn't work without a `RequiredFieldValidator`.

```
<div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="PositionName">
                    Password:</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                    <%--<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rvPassword" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPassword"
                        ErrorMessage="Please Enter Password" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="1"
                        CssClass="error"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>--%>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="PositionName">
                    Confirm Password:</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtConfirmPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqConPass" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtConfirmPassword"
                        ErrorMessage="Please Enter Confirm Password" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="1"
                        CssClass="error"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="compPassword" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtConfirmPassword"
                        ControlToCompare="txtPassword" ErrorMessage="Password Mismatch" SetFocusOnError="True"
                        ValidationGroup="1" CssClass="error"></asp:CompareValidator>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Basically, you can see I have the `RequiredFieldValidator` commented out for both pass and confirm pass.  When I do this, I can submit with only a value in the `txtPassword textbox` and nothing in the `txtConfirmPassword textbox`.

If I uncomment the `RequiredFieldValidators` then it compares as it should.

If it helps, the reason I need to do this is because I am unable to decrypt the password and autofill the textbox with their current password.  So whenever a user is editted, they will need to enter a new password everytime with a `RequiredFieldValidator` on it.

So my solution was to get rid of the `RequiredFieldValidator` and just check if the text is null or empty, and if it is, don't update the password, but if it isn't then update the user without updating the password.

I hope this makes sense, and if anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it.

If you need more info please ask.

Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, this is by design. You can do the compare check server-side or use a custom validator.

Comment: This worked for me perfectly. I copied your given code directly and even without the required validator on password I was given "Password Mismatch" - though it did perform a PostBack in my test.

Comment: Hmm interesting that it worked for you ahwm, still doesn't seem to like it for me.  Oh well, I suppose I will take Henk Holterman's advise and do that check server side.  Thanks guys!

Comment: Additional test note: I even commented the `RequiredFieldValidator` on `txtConfirmPassword` and it worked. So I'm not sure what's interfering with it on yours.

Comment: Ohhh okay, so what happened was the code I pasted didn't have the requiredfieldvalidator commented out for the confirmpassword textbox.  This did make the compare work, however it then wouldn't let me submit without entering a password at all, which is the problem I'm trying to fix.

Answer (score 0):

See this code snippet, in this first for password i have used Regular expression validator and once password is valid then i have enabled compare validator.

```js
 <script>
        function Validate() {            
            if (document.getElementById('<%=txtPassword.ClientID %>').value != "")
                ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%=ConfirmPasswordRequired.ClientID %>'), true);
            else
                ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%=ConfirmPasswordRequired.ClientID %>'), false);
        }
    </script>
```

```html
 <p>
              Password
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
               
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="PasswordRegularExpression" runat="server"
                    ErrorMessage="*Password must be at least 8 characters long and include at least one Special Character, one Number, and one Capital letter."
                    ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1" ValidationExpression="^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\W]).*$"
                    ControlToValidate="txtPassword" >
                </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </p>
            <p>
    Confirm Password:
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtConfirmPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ConfirmPasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtConfirmPassword"
                    ErrorMessage="*Confirm Password is required."
                    Enabled="false" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:CompareValidator ID="NewPasswordCompare" runat="server" ControlToCompare="txtPassword"
                    ControlToValidate="txtConfirmPassword"  ErrorMessage="*Confirm Password must match with the Password."
                    ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1"></asp:CompareValidator>
            </p>
            <p>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1"
                    OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="Validate();" />
            </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one thought, I also ended up using this solution:

How about setting the compare validator to validate the password textbox and compare it to the confirmation.
This way, the compare validator only fires if there is a value inside the password textbox.

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="PositionName">Password:</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"/>      
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="PositionName">Confirm Password:</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtConfirmPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"/>       
        <asp:CompareValidator ID="compPassword" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPassword"
                      ControlToCompare="txtConfirmPassword" ErrorMessage="Password Mismatch" SetFocusOnError="True"
                      ValidationGroup="1" CssClass="error"/>
    </div>
</div>
```